# Quantos Apps posso ter em um projeto Django?

Tags: django

Estou estudando django a pouco tempo, e recentemente vendo um projeto de terceiros, vi que aparentemente ele tinha mais de um app, com isso me surgiu as seguintes duvidas, posso ter mais de um app em um projeto django?
Se sim, qual o objetivo, quando vou precisar ter mais de um app?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.1/intro/reusable-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*posso ter mais de um app em um projeto django?*"

Pode sim

"*Se sim, qual o objetivo, quando vou precisar ter mais de um app?*"

Organização.

Faça o teste de criar mais dois *app* no seu projeto, registre nos *settings*, crie modelos, registre os modelos no *admin.py* e entre na área administrativa.
A real necessidade de ter mais de um app pode ser pessoal (ou até mesmo ter alguma outra vantagem que eu ainda nunca testei, como copiar(crtl+c) o app e inseri-lo num outro projeto, empacotá-lo e instalar via pip como indicado no link enviado pelo bfvaretto...)

Acredito que todo mundo que começa com Django se faz essa mesma pergunta - (Eu mesmo pensei nisso tempos atrás) - e não vejo problema em fazê-la, no entanto é igual cozinhar feijão, é preciso arriscar um pouco mais, testar um pouco mais, errar algumas vezes sem medo de criar um buraco negro que engula a Terra ou invocar o Cthulu